# how to parse text files, where order matters

Tags: java, string, file, text

I'm having trouble determining a way to parse a given text file.

Here is an entry in the file:

```
type = "book"
callnumber = "1"
authors = "a"
title = "t"
publisher = "p"
year = "2023"
```

each entry is separated by a line of whitespace (newline character).

so i have these variables (type, callnumber, authors, title....), and need to read this text and determine what values to set them to. For example, when i read the line "callnumber = 1", then I need set that variable to 1.

This is what I have so far. I read in a line at a time, so `type = "book"` for example, and then I split that line into an array of strings, with the delimiter being ", so the array would contain `type =` and `book` .
Now my problem comes in going further from there. I figured I could cycle through each string in the array, character by character, until I hit whitespace. So i would have `type`, but I don't have any data yet to store in type, and the grab will give me `book` (ignoring the = and whitespace), but how can I attribute book to type?

In summary, I'm looking for a way to  parse a text file line by line, and assign variables values, based on the words I find.

Thanks.

Comment: to clarify, as Aaron got me thinking, I don't necessarily want help with the way I have started to approach the problem. The way I've chosen seems unnecessarily complicated, and I was hoping for someone to point me to a better way, or algorithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ignoring the current route, why not make use of [Properties.load(InputStream inputStream)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29)

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("filename"));

string type = properties.getProperty("type");
System.out.println(type);
```

*book*

Comment: Hmm, that seemed a bit dense for me to understand, can you point to any examples of it in use?

Comment: @Blackbinary Added quick and dirty sample

Comment: perfect, thanks. It spits out `"book"` now, so thats good, just have to get rid of the quotes. One question, I assume if i have a text file with multiple entries (so multiple `type` fields for example), it goes through them in order, if i use multiple calls?

Comment: @Blackbinary You can not have duplicate keys. The more you move down this path, this becomes much more suited for XML

Answer (score 1):

I agree you should take the Properties route if your requirements allow you to.  The next best option would be to deal with each line individually through a regular expression.

```
 String type = "default";
 int callnumber = 0;


 String line = "type = \"book\"";
    // String line = "callnumber = \"1\"";
 Pattern linePattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w*) = \"(.*)\"");

 Matcher matcher = linePattern.matcher(line);
 if ( !matcher.matches() ) {
     System.err.println("Bad line");
 }

 String name = matcher.group(1);
 String value = matcher.group(2);

 if ( "type".equals(name) ) {
     type = value;
 } else if ( "callnumber".equals(name) ) {
     callnumber = Integer.parseInt(value);
 } //...
```

In your case you would want to integrate this into your while loop that reads from the file, and replace `line` with the line you've just read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Aaron's solution:

```
Properties.load(new FileInputStream("<fileName>"));
```

will load the properties and to get any particular property,

use
for example,

```
Properties.getProperty("type")
```

will give you string "book".

Comment: Could you post a barebones example of this? I tried this: `import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class reader {
 
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    Properties.load(new FileInputStream ("data.txt"));
    String data = Properties.getProperty("type");
    System.out.println(data);
  }
 
}` but i got errors about non-static method can't be referenced by static context

Answer (score 0):

Assigning values to variables has probably been done elsewhere more cleanly. If you want to 'tokenize' your string however, use a string tokenizer.

The new school is to use the split method of the String class.

```
token[] = line.split("\s++")
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Below is the old school way:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

```
While(String line = someInput.readLine())

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line)
while(st.hasMoreTokens)
{
  String token = st.nextToken()
  //branch on token command, skip token '=', and assign on values
}
```

Comment: Funny, my Java version says StringTokenizer is a legacy class whose use in new code is discouraged :-P.

Comment: Indeed.  Haven't java'd in a while.  Look's like String.split() can be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is the order of the variables in the text file always going to be the same?

I'm guessing you wouldn't be asking if that was the case.

Why not just make a method:

```
void assignVariableByName(String name, <type> value) {
    if(name.contains("type"))
        type = value;
    else if(name.contains("callnumber"))
        callnumber = value; 
}
```

Then usage ->

You have the array of strings you split... and you call

```
assignVariableByName(parsedLine[0],parsedLine[1]);
```